# Has this function an effect on toplevel?

Tags: clisp

I would like to know if this function has an effect on top-level symbols?

```
(defun test (gallon)
  (setq cup '(D D D D))
  (pop cup) )
```

If the answer is yes, which one?

And want to know how to fix this function to prevent this side effect?
Thank you for answering!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you compile this function, you will get the warnings:

```
WARNING: in TEST : CUP is neither declared nor bound,
         it will be treated as if it were declared SPECIAL.
WARNING: in TEST : CUP is neither declared nor bound,
         it will be treated as if it were declared SPECIAL.
WARNING: in TEST : CUP is neither declared nor bound,
         it will be treated as if it were declared SPECIAL.
WARNING: in TEST : CUP is neither declared nor bound,
         it will be treated as if it were declared SPECIAL.
WARNING: in TEST : variable GALLON is not used.
         Misspelled or missing IGNORE declaration?
```

this tells you that you are not binding `cup` and not using `gallon`.

**What is happening is that you are creating (and modifying) a global variable `cup`.**

To avoid it, you should bind it locally:

```
(defun test1 (gallon)
  (let ((cup '(D D D D)))
    (pop cup)))
```

**note** that you are still ignoring the `gallon` argument.

To see the difference, observe

```
cup
==> undefined variable error
(test)
==> D
cup
==> (D D D)
(setq cup 10)
==> 10
(test1)
==> D
cup 
==> 10
```

i.e., my `test1` does *not* modify the global binding.